# What is implied by "Lass uns Herzrasen"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know it translates directly to "let us heart race" but what is it trying to say? Let's make our hearts race? Let's make our hearts beat faster by doing "something"?

Comment: It depends on the context. Where is it from?

Comment: Did you consider to think yourself what it might be? A little tip: Google for heart, race and love.

Comment: It *could* refer to "drinking a very strong coffee together" - but it doesn't, I suppose

Answer (score 1):

I think it's from this [Namika's song »Herzrasen«](http://www.songtexte.com/songtext/namika/herzrasen-7b7a8244.html).

*Das Herzrasen* is a very high pulse and also a medical condition. Here, it's used in a very odd analogy to *das Rasen*, racing a car. Notable: The substantive *Herzrasen* is turned back into a verb *herzrasen*, which did not exist. Until now.